# problems comes while creating virtualenv

Tags: python, pyenv-virtualenv

I have installed python 3.10.2, while creating virtualenv
I did pip install virtualenv. then I create myenv (virtualenv mypython), but I got error like this. could you please help me what do I do
the error is :

C:\Users\ARROWIN PHOTOGRAPHY\Felix\djangoProject>virtualenv mypython
'virtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: to create virtual environment you can do `python -m venv path/to/your/virtualenvironment`

Comment: 'virtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. same problem comes again

Comment: 'venv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.this also again comes

Answer (score 1):

In python3 is better to use `venv` instead. Here are the steps to create your environment:

In your project directory, open the terminal:

> python3 -m venv venv

Then:

> source venv/bin/activate

Comment: Note that `venv` may not be installed by default.  On Ubuntu, for example, you need to install the `python3-venv` package.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have set up the python PATH variables correctly and that in your path e.g. `..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts` you can locate the python executable virtualenv.exe

If you are using multiple python versions on your local machine be careful while using PIP install. It is better to use the command `pip3.x install ...` (x is meant to be a specific version of pip e.g. pip3.9) so you can be sure you installed the virtualenv in the correct version of Python, and afterward, you can also select a specific python version when using virtualenv by `virtualenv env -p pythonxx` the xx is meant as a python version.